# Tables jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have two issues. I am trying to dynamically create tables when the "enter" button is pressed.

```
function commandLine() {
    $('#write').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var $table = $('<table>');
            //tbody
            var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');
            // add row
            $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
                .append("<td>Router#</td>");
            // add table to dom
            $table.appendTo('#console');
        }
    });

}
```

This code works however when I hit enter I get 3 rows and no columns.  I need to hit enter and get 1 row with 2 columns. Please help!

Comment: Well, `<tr />` isn't a valid tag, so that may have to do with it. What is showing via View source?

Comment: Where did you intend to create the second column's cell?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am getting it perfectly fine here. You haven't specified the second column or whatsoever. In your code, the column thing is here:

```
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
    .append("<td>Router#</td>").append("<td>Column 2</td>");
//                             ^ Add second column's cell
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/EZpgF/